# php i got Uncaught Error Function name must be a string in

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, pdo, fatal-error

i on doing project make web application that automaticly generate number. and i get this error :

**Notice: Undefined variable: getRomawi in C:\xampp\htdocs\bigweb\number_generate.php on line 5**

**Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Function name must be a string in C:\xampp\htdocs\bigweb\number_generate.php:5 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\bigweb\save.php(3): require_once() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\bigweb\number_generate.php on line 5**

i already searching on google but i didn't find any topic that exactly same like my case, and here is the code :

**number_generate.php**

```
<?php
include "fungsi_romawi.php";
include "save.php";
$month = date('n');
$romawi = $getRomawi($month);
$year = date('Y');
$number = "/YMMI/".$romawi."/".$year;

$query = "SELECT MAX(number_out) as MAXKODE FROM bigdata_admin WHERE month(date_in)='$month'";
$hasil = mysqli_query($query); 
$data = mysqli_fetch_array($hasil);
$no = $data['MAXKODE'];
$Gnome = $no+1;

$kode = sprintf("%02s", $Gnome);
$nomerbaru = $kode.$number;
?>'''
```

and this is other file that link to first error, i made multiple file php :

**fungsi_romawi.php**

```
<?php
function getRomawi($month)
{
    switch($month)
    {case '1': 
            return "I";
            break;
        case '2':
            return "II";
            break;
        case '3':
            return "III";
            break;
        case '4':
            return "IV";
            break;
        case '5':
            return "V";
            break;
        case '6':
            return "VI";
            break;
        case '7':
            return "VII";
            break;
        case '8':
            return "VIII";
            break;
        case '9':
            return "IX";
            break;
        case '10':
            return "X";
            break;
        case '11':
            return "XI";
            break;
        case '12':
            return "XII";
            break;}
}
?>
```

and last this is **save.php** that will show the number :

```
<?php
if (!empty($_POST['signup']));
require_once "number_generate.php";

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "bigdata";
{
$id_in = (FILTER_VAR($_POST['id_in'], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT));
$name_in = (FILTER_VAR($_POST['name_in'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));
$dept_in = (FILTER_VAR($_POST['dept_in'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));
$information_in = (FILTER_VAR($_POST['information_in'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));
$date_in = $_POST['date_in'];

try 
{
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO bigdata_admin (id_in, name_in, dept_in, information_in,      date_in) 
                            VALUES (:id_in, :name_in, :dept_in, :information_in, :date_in)");
    $stmt->bindParam(":id_in", $id_in,PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindParam(":name_in", $name_in,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(":dept_in", $dept_in,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(":information_in", $information_in,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(":date_in", $date_in,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();
}
    catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
}
$conn = null;
?>
```

sorry for long posting, any advice will be appreciate and very helpful

Comment: $romawi = $getRomawi($month); This is the issue, you are calling function with a $, therefore it is treated as variable. Remove $ and call function like this getRomawi

Comment: thankyou for your response @PrabhjotSinghKainth, but i got another error :    Fatal error: Cannot redeclare getRomawi() (previously declared in C:\xampp\htdocs\bigweb\fungsi_romawi.php:2) in C:\xampp\htdocs\bigweb\fungsi_romawi.php on line 43

Answer (score -1):

You need to remove $ sign :

```
$romawi = $getRomawi($month);
```

TO

```
 $romawi = getRomawi($month);
```

**Note:** A function name must start with a letter or an underscore. Function names are NOT case-sensitive.

Comment: This should not be posted as answer, it should have been a comment.

Comment: why should not be posted as answer. may i know the reason ?

Comment: Thankyou very much for your advice @Ramki, but when i change it as your hint i get an error : Fatal error: Cannot redeclare getRomawi() (previously declared in C:\xampp\htdocs\bigweb\fungsi_romawi.php:2) in C:\xampp\htdocs\bigweb\fungsi_romawi.php on line 43 
and sorry for double comment.

Comment: can u check that same function name(getRomawi) already exist or not ?

Comment: Questions that are a result of a simple typographic error are off-topic for the site. Instead of answering, flag it for closure, and leave a comment.